# How can I know if a file open in excel is saved or not?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to find a way to be able to detect if the file on which my taskpane add-in is currently running is saved or not. I know that it is possible to do this in word add-ins but I want it for excel add-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `workbook.properties` API to get the `creationDate`, the workbook is not saved if you get `null`

A sample code that you could try

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let docProperties = context.workbook.properties;

    docProperties.load("creationDate");
    await context.sync();

    console.log("Workbook creation date: " + docProperties.creationDate.toDateString());
  });
```

Comment: This will tell me if its saved or not only the first time, I would like to keep checking saved and unsaved states

Comment: We have an autosave feature, it will automatically save the workbook in every 30 seconds. do you mean you want to know whether the document is saved or not within 30 seconds?

Comment: btw, may I know which word API that you use to detect the save state?

Comment: Yes I want to know when the file is saved and unsaved, I was able to do this in word just by checking the document.saved property every few seconds and keeping a check on its previous state but document.saved property does not seem to work in excel

Comment: Maybe there is an equivalent to document.saved in excel?

Comment: So far Excel JS API doesn't have document.saved API. I am curious about the scenario for requesting to check the saved status every few seconds. but it looks to me you would like to have an onSaved event?

Comment: Yes an onSaved Event would be perfect, another important scenario to catch the save event would be when the user closes the word app and there is a prompt to save the file if it is already not saved, if we could somehow catch this event as well it would be amazing :)

Comment: Thanks, would you please submit your request in uservoice and upvote this feature https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563